# How to call stored procedure in laravel5?

Tags: php, laravel-5

I am new in laravel5. i need to require call stored procedure in my application. so i don't know how to call and where to call. is it right way to call stored procedure. pls anyone suggest me.

Comment: Do you want to sacrifice ORM ?

Answer (score 0):

It was as simple like

```
$Result = DB::select('CALL YourProcedure(?,?)',array($YourParameter,$YourParameter1));
```

And the `$Result` was probably the output of your stored procedure

Answer (score 0):

Try this.
with parameter

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure(?,?,..)',array($Param1,$param2));
```

and without parameter

```
DB::select('exec my_stored_procedure');
```